# I want to add numbers between a large set of numbers in a graph in matplotlib(python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

above 350 There is a node so i want it to add the exact number on the nodes so 363 as in the picture

and remove all useless numbers that dont have nodes on them and i also want to connect the nodes to the x and y like:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

and maybe make the lines like red or smth too
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2H1G1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done this way utilizing the matplotlib scripting layer

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# generating some random data kinda similar to the OP's
slope = -1
intercept = 413

x = np.random.randint(-50, 400, size=10)
y = slope*x + intercept

# scatter plot
plt.scatter(x, y)

# showing ticks only on available data
plt.xticks(x, x, rotation=90)
plt.yticks(y, y)

# setting limits on the x and the y
margin = 10
x_min, x_max = (x.min() - margin, x.max() + margin)
y_min, y_max = (y.min() - margin, y.max() + margin)

plt.xlim(x_min, x_max)
plt.ylim(y_min, y_max)

# connecting nodes to the x and the y
plt.hlines(y, x_min, x)
plt.vlines(x, y_min, y)

plt.show()
```

[image: Example]